# Blender 2.9 Backdrop grid changed

Tags: compositing-nodes

So I wanted to work in the compositor but the window area pattern changed to this mess, and it actually hurts to look when I move the screen to check bigger nodes groups.

[image: Grid Backdrop Background]

any way to get it back to the original one?
[I know the image is of version 2.8; focus on the compositor window background]

[image: Google Image]